Texture Paint in Blender missing details and losing quality?
there's this weird bug that's been annoying me for a long time and it happens sometimes when I move from one texture to another.
this is what it looks after the bug:


second pic is from the image select option, as you can see there's a lot more detail to it than the first image.

Please take a look at the preview of your question if it looks like you really want to post it like that before you actually do it. I cannot see any second picture.

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

Are you using an addon like Ucupaint for reading the image into a preview? There isn't enough info in the images here to see what is going on other than the reduced size thumbnail appears to have a disproportionate black detail to red area in contrast to the larger image. This doesn't mean something wrong with Blender though, as the full scale image is the information being worked on, not a faulty thumbnail preview. Main point is this: are your painting sessions achieving the level of detail on the model as expected, or is there some loss there? Disregarding the preview thumbnail.
